# Timber v2 Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

We are using Timber v1 but are now required to migrate to v2 since Dreamhost will soon require that all sites are upgraded to PHP8.*]

Problem is, the new version is now working following the instructions. Here's the current fatal error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to protected method Timber\Timber::init() from global scope in /home/wp_q5bibz/incrementumdigitalcom.stage.site/wp-content/themes/id/functions.php:26

Followed the instruction here: https://timber.github.io/docs/v2/installation/

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the latest version is `2.0.0-rc.1`. If you install Timber via Composer, make sure to install this specific version via `composer require timber/timber:2.0.0-rc.1` or change it in your `composer.json`.

Alternatively, download it [from GitHub](https://github.com/timber/timber/releases/tag/2.0.0-rc.1).

For more context, composer is currently automatically pulling timber/timber 1.22.1 as of early Oct.  If you are new to composer, you can check all package versions with `composer.phar show`.  When updating to timber/timber:2.0.0-rc.1, you might also need to update dependencies.  Composer will let you know what dependencies and you can update them with composer update package/package

Comment: If you download it from GitHub, the required dependencies will not be installed. It’s not like a plugin that comes with all files. It’s managed with Composer, so you should install it through Composer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure *which* fix got me there, but there original poster is correct that the Starter theme "as-is" (`2.0.0`, Dec. 7, 2023) is non-functional on default install.

In addition, there's some documentation in the Timber 2.x handbook (as of this post in Feb 2024), which seems non-functional as well.

---

1. Use the latest version of Timber.

- Make the following change and run `composer install`.
- (If you've already run `composer install` either delete the generated `composer.lock` file or run `composer update timber/timber --with-dependencies` instead of `composer install`.)

```json
"require": {
        "timber/timber": "^2.0"
    },
```

2. Comment out these two lines from The StarterSite class-file. (The tooling within them matches the OLD 2.x setup, but not the NEW setup.)

```php
add_filter( 'timber/twig', array( $this, 'add_to_twig' ) );
add_filter( 'timber/twig/environment/options', [ $this, 'update_twig_environment_options' ] );
```

(I got my custom Twig function to work using the [old-school method](https://timber.github.io/docs/v2/guides/extending-twig/#adding-functionality-with-the-twig-environment-filter), but even the official documentation behind [enabling auto-escaping](https://timber.github.io/docs/v2/guides/escaping/#escaping-in-timber) seems non-functional altogether.)

3. I added PSR-4 autoloading, which seemed to help:

- Add `namespace StarterSite;` to the top of `src/Startersite.php`
- Comment out and/or remove the `require_once` tag for the `StarterSite.php`, since Composer auto-loading will handle it.
- Add the following to to your theme-level `composer.json` file:

```json
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
       "StarterSite\\" : "src"
   }
}
```

- Run `composer install`

4. I did enough that I'm not sure THIS step made a difference.

- I didn't trust the "Timber" autoloading, because it didn't seem to work?
- Instead I started adding `use Timber\Timber;` and/or `use Timber{ Site, Timber };` as needed on `functions.php`, my template files, and the `StaterSite.php` class file.